# TestContext class not found in .NET-core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I am moving and refactoring a code from .NET-Framework to .NET-Core in C#. When I run a simple test on a method which is supposed to sort a List, I get this error:

> "System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.IDictionary Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext.get_Properties()'."

I have checked references to other namespaces that are necessary. I searched for the error online and I realized that the TestContext Class has not been provided in .NET Core yet! Is there another way or a replacement library I can use instead? Thank you.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            // Arrange
            // Grab an arbitrary start time.
            Time startTime = Time.Now;

            List<TimeValue> values = new List<TimeValue>
            {
                // Make sure that second timestamp comes before the first 
                   timestamp
                new TimeValue(startTime.PlusMinutes(1)),
                new TimeValue(startTime)
            };

            // Ensure that this is sorted in ascending order of time.
            List<TimeValue> expectedValues = values.OrderBy(value => 
            value.Timestamp).ToList();
            CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(expectedValues, values);

            // Act
            SortArray myObj = new SortArray(values);

            // Assert
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedValues, SortArray.Values);
        }
```

I expect the TestMethod to run, but it does not run and gives me the following error:

> 'System.Collections.IDictionary Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext.get_Properties()'.

Comment: I've had this problem recently. The solution was the correct configuration of the path of the test adapter when invoking the test runner. Like: ..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible alternate you could use is [xUnit](https://xunit.net/). Its a open sourced tool and you can use it with .NET Core.

Microsoft offers a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test) on how to xUnit with the .NET Core.

Another possibility is "dotnet test" which is a unit testing tool that Microsoft made compatible for .NET Core.

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference. If that site goes down or the link goes dead, it renders your answer useless.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Thanks for letting me know. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your test class the following property:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

In general, `MSTest` does not seem to be actively developed. As it's shipped with `Visual Studio`, Microsoft [keeps it working](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/) on `.NET` (and [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953827/what-is-the-replacement-for-testcontext-datarowmycolumnname) even on `.NET Core`) but they seem to use `xUnit` themselves internally, so it makes sense to consider switching your tests to `xUnit` either.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you provide a **field** of type TestContext. It doesn't work when you make it a **property**. Following works with .NET Core 3.1 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest).

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TimeLogger.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class YourTestClass
    {
        private static TestContext Context;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void InitClass(TestContext testContext)
        {
            Context = testContext;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_1()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_2()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

But after changing

```
    private static TestContext Context;
```

into

```
    private static TestContext Context { get; set; }
```

causes tests don't run anymore.

Comment: TestContext should not be a static so why this should work is more than I understand. With Dotnet core 3.1 I can use `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }` as [@dmitry-pavlov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56859075/521554) writes.